# How does magento model rewrite works?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I understand how to override/rewrite core models in our custom module in magento, I just want to understand how does it works?
In which file these rewrites are takes place.
for example 
if I want to rewrite core/resource.php model I need to add

```
<models>
<core>
 <rewrite>  
      <resource>Clipcart_Externaldb_Model_Resource</resource>
 </rewrite>
 </core>
</models>
```

I just want to know how does it works?
Thanks!.

Comment: I suggest you read this old post on [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) which I believe is still applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting modules in Magento is a double-edged sword. While it can be very helpful for instances where there is no events to consume, rewrites can also cause major headaches to you and other developers who work on this project, and modules that you might try to install in the future (although they shouldn't do much rewriting for the same reason).

Personally, I work to rewrite a little as possible. When I have to, I just rewrite in modules specifically for a client, and not deployed to many in modules.

## Rewriting Background:

That said, rewriting is super simple. Rewrites happen in `config.xml` of your module. In `config.xml`, there are sections denoting information about `models`, `blocks`, and `helpers`:

```
<config>
    <modules><!-- module information here --></modules>
    <global>
        <models><!-- your module's model config here --></models>
        <blocks><!-- your module's blocks config here --></blocks>
        <helpers><!-- your module's helpers config here --></helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Before you rewrite, you need to determine what you are rewriting. In your example (please be careful rewriting `core/resource`, as I can see there being much better alternatives). Rewriting `core/resource` is different than normal (it's configuration is in app/etc/config.xml), but it's concepts are the same.

### How to Rewrite:

To make this easier to understand, I am going to rewrite `cataloginventory/stock_item`. In the `models` node of your `config.xml`, add:

```
<cataloginventory>
    <rewrite>
        <stock_item>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Override_CatalogInventory_Stock_Item</stock_item>
    </rewrite>
</cataloginventory>
```

Breaking this up is easy. In the string, `cataloginventory/stock_item`, the module (first/last lines) is `<cataloginventory/>`. The `<rewrite/>` node goes inside of this. Then, what is after the slash goes inside `<rewrite/>`.

And, `YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Override_CatalogInventory_Stock_Item` is the name of the class that is being loaded instead of `cataloginventory/stock_item`. I like to put the overrides in an override folder.

The one gotcha is with resource models. If the model you need to rewrite has `mysql4` or `resource` in the class, then you need to look in that module's config.xml to find out the "module name" of the modules resource model.